# HQL: get last element of collection

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have Person entity, which have many-to-many relationship with Address entity (which has some boolean property). This relationship represent with help of separate table (which is not an entity)

I need a query like:
"from Person p where p.addresses is empty or p.addresses.getLastElement.propert is TRUE"

***Question:***

1. Can I pull the last element of p.addresses collection in HQL question? If yes, How?
2. If no, can I represent many-to-many relationship as entity?

Comment: You want to fetch the last entity of collection or you just want to check it's property's value?

Comment: I want to fetch last element of collection and check properties of that (the last) element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I pull the last element of p.addresses collection in HQL question?
>   If yes, How?

For this question, you can try out the following:

```
from Person p where p.addresses[size(p.addresses) - 1].propert = TRUE
```

This won't fetch the last entity of collection but will check the last entity's property's value & will fetch `Person` accordingly.