# JPQL - filter based on last updated timestamp attribute inside @ElementCollection elements

Tags: jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have @Entity-s (Order) that may change their state. Each state-change is represented with an @Embeddable object (OrderUpdate), added to an @ElementCollection (Order.updates). How can I query Orders based on the most recent update?

My goal is to select those Orders, where the last update's state is DONE.

Order:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<OrderUpdate> updates;
    ...
```

OrderUpdate:

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderUpdate {

    @ManyToOne
    private User host;

    private String state;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    ...
```

OrderRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, UUID> {

    @Query("select o from Order o where [o.updates.last.state TODO] = DONE")
    Set<Order> findDone();

}
```

Comment: If using Hibernate, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681268/hql-get-last-element-of-collection?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

`@Query("select o from Order o inner join o.updates u where u.state = ''DONE'' and u.timestamp = (select max(u2.timestamp) from Order o2 inner join o2.updates u2 where o2.id = o.id))`  If I understand correclty

Comment: I updated my question: "My goal is to select those Orders, where the last update's state is DONE"

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `last update state` ... I only see `state` variable in the object .. so what is `last update`

Comment: last you mean latest timestamp ? so it should be last and DONE at the same time you mean, right ?

Comment: I edited the answer , note the two consecutive single quotes

Comment: is it ok then ??

Comment: 1. unexpected token: DONE => fixed by using single quotes
2. 'and' keyword is missing after 'DONE'
3. illegal attempt to dereference collection [order0_.id.updates] with element property reference [state]

Comment: 1. as I mentioned 2. a typo, I fixed 3.sorry I missed something, I fixed it according to JB Nizet's answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975468/illegal-attempt-to-dereference-collection-when-querying-using-jpa-relations